# Locked out of Ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, password-recovery, recovery-mode

I have install Ubuntu-touch on my Nexus 5 and everything worked alright.
Until today I had set up a 4 digit locking password, that worked.
I changed it to a "regular password" but once changed I could not log in even though I am confident that I use the same password.
ADB does not seem to work since I guess I would have to unlock the phone first.

Is there a way to recover the account or change the password ?

I see the recovery has a "wipe data / factory reset option" but I don't find too much documentation about it. What will be the state (wrt system and apps updates) of the phone afterward ?

Answer (score 2):

Since I needed the phone I went with the "wip data / factory reset" option from the recovery.

It worked as follows : all user data wiped and Ubuntu Touch restored to lattest update, that solved my problem.